# Swift Schedule NSLocalNotification after NSLocalNotification was executed in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I want to create a App that sends info to the user with local notifications.

When a local notification is send, another notification should be scheduled (when the app is running in the background). I want to be able to change the properties of the next notification to create a stream of notifications with different time intervals and text.

I know how to schedule a single notification and I tried to work with didReceiveLocalNotification but I did not achieve the results I want.

The logic would be. App goes to background -> schedules a notification -> notification shows up -> app sets properties of another notification in the background -> app schedules the other notification in the background -> app stays in the background -> notification shows up -> app sets properties of another notification ...

Can you help me here?
Thanks,
Tobias

Comment: You need to determine which background mode can work for you - apps can't execute arbitrarily in the background on iOS.  Have a look at the iOS application programming guide.  Perhaps background refresh mode can work for you

Comment: Mhm the background refresh mode time interval can't be set... Then it seems impossible to do what I want to do :/ or better to say it seems to be impossible with local notifications ...

Comment: If you want precise control then server-based push notification scheduling is more reliable

Comment: Mhm I wanted to try to go completly without any needs of a server. It is really strange that I can't create a app that sends me for example random jokes at random times throughout my day, without the need o visiting the app avery now and then right?

Comment: That's just the way it is.  You can schedule about 20 local notifications at a time.  I guess if the user hasn't launched your app after 20 jokes then they aren't interested...:)

Comment: Haha :D I just wanted to see how far I can get with local notifications. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

After a long research and Paulws comment I need to come to the conclusion, that the task I am after is not possible with Apples Local Notifications. For this type of task one needs to use push notifications to be able to schedule regular notifications over a longer period of time.